# Running a Python script as a service file on boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, services, systemd-startup

I have a Python script (that works) set up and I want to run it automatically every time the Raspberry Pi is on.

I have read that I need to create a unit file and I have done so, but whenever I try these commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable myscript.service

sudo systemctl start myscript.service

sudo systemctl stop myscript.service
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to start myfile.service. Unit myfile.service not found.
```

I have no idea if the problem is that I am saving the file and the script in the wrong places or if I am missing something else. Help?

Both hs110-data-collect-py (the python script) and the unit file hs110.service are saved in:
/home/pi/hs110

**************************** UPDATE

After doing what Ingo suggested, I get this message:

```
* hs110.service - hs110 data collection
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hs110.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-03-21 12:06:43 CET; 1min 6s ago
 Main PID: 828 (python3)
   CGroup: /system.slice/hs110.service
           `-828 /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hs110-data-collect.py

Mar 21 12:06:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started hs110 data collection.
Mar 21 12:06:45 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:06:45 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

************************UPDATE

When I use `journalctl --boot --unit=hs110.service` to see the output of the script in the terminal, I get this message:

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 18:16:43 CET, end at Thu 2019-03-21 12:35:01 CET. --
Mar 21 12:06:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started hs110 data collection.
Mar 21 12:06:45 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:06:45 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: Socket closed.
Mar 21 12:20:29 raspberrypi python3[828]: No data returned on power request.
```

The problem is that I should get this "socket closed" message every 5 seconds (this happens when I just write `python3 hs110-data-collect.py` ). So why don't I get a return message every 5 seconds in the journal?

Comment: Please edit the question and add more information, e.g. the file location.

Comment: put the unit file in either /lib/systemd/system/ or /etc/systemd/system/

Comment: I cannot do it since I have "no permission"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nothing about your script, if it runs only one time on boot up or stays always in the background as a service, if it needs root rights, if it produces text or graphical output, to name the most important one. But for a first try you can start with a generic unit file that can be modified to your needs.

Create a new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit hs110.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=hs110 data collection
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hs110-data-collect.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable the service and reboot:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable hs110.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

Look at its status with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status hs110.service
```

As you told in a comment the script will do text output only on the console. If it is running as service you will find this output in the systemd journal:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot --unit=hs110.service
```

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks for your help. I did what you said and I am adding the message I got to my original question now.

Comment: @xoani exec code 203 means "no such file or directory". Seems your python script isn't set executable. Change the line `ExecStart=`. I have updated the answer. Please just replace the status message in your question. Also login as user **pi** and execute `python3 /home/pi/hs110-data-collect.py`. Does it work? Do you have some output? If so, is it just text on the console? Does the script runs only one time and terminates, or is it running all the time to collect data continuously?

Comment: I have updated the message. It seems like the script is running on boot now (it worked before, just not on boot). When I start the script manually, the data is collected every  5 seconds and I see that in the RPi terminal. Now this message shows that the data got collected once at 12:06:45 but it doesn't show that it gets collected every 5 seconds. Is this correct? (Just to clarify, the "no data returned on power request" is the right message at the moment, because I don't have any data yet, so this is what the output should be)

Comment: @xoani OK, your script is running now as service. I cannot say anything about its execution because I don't know something about it. If it outputs every 5 seconds that it has collected data then you should find this message with `journalctl`. I have updated the answer at the end. But a logging message every 5 sec will fill your journal fast and make it a huge file. It is up to you to optimize the script. It would be nice if you could accept my answer with a tick at the tick on the left side. This will finish the question and show others that it has a solution.

Comment: Hello, I accepted the answer, thanks for the heads up and for all your help! The script runs in the background but I am confused because in the journal the times are not every 5 seconds (there are a lot of messages at 12:20:29). But when I run the script manually, I do get a message in return every 5 seconds. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @xoani No idea. It's a behavior of the script and as already said, without knowing what does the script do, nobody can say something about it. It may be possible that it does not find exactly the same environment as when you run it on the command line. You may also look at the whole journal with `journalctl -b -e` if you find something. If you do not find a solution then you can ask a new question.